# Why Post-Processing v1 not works in WebGL build?

Tags: unity, webgl

In my WebGL browser app, i've tried to add Post Processing (first version) stack.

I'm using Unity 2018.4.6f1 (i started 1 years ago to develop this app).

I've added Post Processing Behaviour to my Camera, and this is what i've enabled:

[image]

When i run my scene on Chrome or Firefox, Camera appears all black but UI is correctly rendered.

Are there any incompatibility issue using Post Processing and WebGL ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try enabling just one effect at a time, to work out whether it's specific effects that don't work, or all of them? Before activating the post processing stack, were you using HDR or deferred rendering? Some of these post processing options might be forcing the rendering to use those paths or something equivalent.

Comment: You're right; after removing some effect and leaving just bloom, now it works .. Strange beheviour anyway!

Comment: If you can narrow down one effect that causes the problem, we might be able to diagnose why, or suggest fixes or alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

PPS is not supported on WebGL 1. You should have Webgl2 capable browser and GPU required to run WEBGL 2.  You can test [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl2) or [this](https://webglreport.com/?v=2) for WEBGL2 support on your browser. Fore more read [this post](https://researchandprogram.blogspot.com/2020/08/post-processing-and-unity-webgl.html).